# GMS update - How apkmirror website gets GMS update for Android apps

Tags: android, app-update

I am using [APKMIRROR](https://www.apkmirror.com/)  for a while for distributing my apps to my customers. It works perfectly to show app updates to my customers. I understand how app update functionality works in devices via Google Play Store.

I am curious to know how the APK update works in [APKMIRROR](https://www.apkmirror.com/) ? I really want to know how the technology works behind?

Thanks,
Kanak